# Generate imageView based off array.count - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, for-loop, imageview

I am trying to generate a section of image views which will sit at the top of an application and update as the user progresses through the quiz.

My array variable is Qs, the code I have to generate an imageView is as follows:

```
var imageView: UIImageView!
var i = 0
var total = Int(Qs.capacity) // Just testing what .capacity does.

for i in 0..<(Qs.count-1){
imageView - UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 75, width: 50, height: 50))
imageView.image = UIImage(named:"InfoIcon")
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

self.view.addSubView(imageView)
}
```

I already have a variable which tracks the users progress through the quiz with just an integer if that would be any help, its declared along with the quiz functionality.
Here is a fantastically draw visual of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you have a container `view` attached at the top, then you can use this method to add any number of `imageView's`.

```
func addProgressImages(to view: UIView, count: Int) {
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

    for i in 0..<count {
        let spacing: CGFloat = 2
        let tag = i + 888
        let width: CGFloat = screenSize.width/CGFloat(count)
        let height: CGFloat = width
        if let view = view.viewWithTag(tag) {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        let x = spacing + CGFloat(i) * width
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: 100, width: width - spacing, height: height))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named:"InfoIcon")
        imageView.tag = tag
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

You can play with `y` value for `vertical` alignment.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the response, I'm having some trouble calling the function, inside the viewDidLoad() function I called     addProgressImages(to: UIView, count: Int) I am getting a cannot convert value of type UIView.Type to expected argument type UIView

Comment: ahh. you have to pass the actual view and number here like `addProgressImages(to: self.view, count: 5) `

Comment: Thanks for getting around that problem, now theres an issue where I am getting a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error on a prepare for segue function, is there anything from that code which causes this error?

Comment: hey, i'm not sure what is wrong with the code but even without your code the application will not run anymore due to this thread 1 error, do you have any advice?

Comment: Sorry, i can not figure out the issue without knowing the line of code where it is crashing. You might have to debug your app and find the reason for that crash.

Comment: the line of code which seems to be causing the issue is: let SC =  segue.destination as! QuizEndViewController  I don't understand why this is an error now as there was no issue with it before.

Comment: change `!` to `?` in `prepare(for segue` method and check. Most probably you didn't set `ViewController` class in `storyboard` to `QuizEndViewController`

Comment: I got it working with the change from ! to ?, thanks for the help tho i really appreciate it, this project is pissing me off lol

Comment: Glad it helped. But what about the images? Are they getting added correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately not, for some reason its  just like nothing is happening with that code, I'm trying to find some code online to see if there are other ways of doing it

Comment: It should work also. Do you have the image with name `InfoIcon` in your `assets`? Can you put breakpoints to see if you are able to reach `view.addSubview(imageView)`

Comment: Yeah the InfoIcon is inside the assets, I am just using that image as a placeholder till it is working, it's used previously in the project. I'm working on breakpoints just now, it seems to get to the view.addsubview line but nothing will appear on the app, its pretty weird that there is nothing happening, it's probably something stupid I'm missing

Comment: Is there any other `View` in this `ViewController`? Because it might be possible that there is some other view that is hiding these images. Can you verify that using `Debug View Hierarchy`?

Comment: Alright, through the debug view hierarchy it shows that indeed the image views are being created, however they are all being placed on top of one another at the top left of the view, almost like there are no constraints set up. there is also not the correct amount of them being created although that should be easier to fix i imagine

Comment: Let me make a slight update to answer to fix at least one issue. Replace this method now and re-run to see if it resolves the number of images issue? For position i believe you can play with x and y easily.

Comment: I've put all the code in but there is an error on using * on a float value, its on the line let x = i * width  its saying * cannot be applied to operands of type int and cgfloat

Comment: Yes, fixed. Try now.

Comment: Yeah man its working now, just changed the y position too to make it visible in the application. Do you know if theres a way to make the imageviews scale so if there is say 11 imageviews it will display them all on the page as opposed to displaying the first 8 and the rest leading off the interface

Comment: Updated the answer. Just change the `y`to your desired value, the rest will be handled.

Comment: Added few more optimizations. Please update to latest!

Comment: Thank you so much, you have no idea how long I have been trying to do this haha. Sorry about the elongated answers etc, have a good one

Comment: Yeah, i think we already made comments section ugly for someone to follow along :). Glad it helped!